# Covariance between two products of two different type of random variable

Tags: variance, covariance-matrix

Let's say there are four random variables: $A_1$, $A_2$, $B_1$, $B_2$

Same letter correlated;  different letter independent:

- $A_1$ and $B_1$ independent
- $A_1$ and $B_2$ independent
- $A_1$ and $A_2$ dependent
- $B_1$ and $B_2$ dependent

Let's think about product of them.
I know that if $X$ and $Y$ are independent, $E(X Y)=E(X) E(Y)$
I know that for a variance case.
$$Var(A_1 B_1 )=E(B_1)^2 Var(A_1 ) +E(A_1)^2 Var(B_1)+Var(A_1 )Var(B_1 )$$

What about covariance? For example, is this below correct?
$$Cov(A_1 B_1,  A_2 B_2 )=E(A_1 B_1 A_2 B_2 )-E(A_1 B_1 )E(A_2 B_2 )
=E(A_1 A_2)E(B_1 B_2 )-E(A_1)E(B_1)E(A_2)E(B_2)
$$

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Covariance  covariance

Comment: You are right. So I shouldn't say two different kind of random variables, X_i 1<=i<=N  Y_i 1<=i<=N so 2N different kind of random variables, and X_i and Y_i are independent, but X_i and X_j are dependent.

Comment: I edited to the minimum point..